# How to iterate through all sub classes of a parent class using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The parent class on a website houses multiple other classes whose names and xpaths change while the parent remains the same. I want to iterate through all the sub classes and get the src link that each of them have. Here is an image of the parent class highlighted with the sub classes showing src links:

[Parent class with sub class links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VbPe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
driver = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.gyggcyz0.du4w35lb')
divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div')
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img')

classes = [item.get_attribute("class") for item in divs]
srcs = [item.get_attribute("src") for item in imgs]
```

You will get all the classes in list classes, srcs in list srcs.